# How I can solve error CS0201 in Unity to end the game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good evening.
I want to ask about Unity's problem I met.
I made pong-like game and I made 2 scripts for turning game scene to the result when ball hits to the ball behind the plays, However when I insert them to the wall and GameManagement object, the error of "error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement" was come out.
I'd like to know any solution for this problem 
Thank you.

Game management Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameMaster : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void GameOver()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Result");
    }
}
```

Script for wall to Check hit or not

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameoverPlayer1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){
        GameObject.Find("GameMaster").GetComponent<GameMaster>().GameOver;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the GameOver as a Method.

```
GameObject.Find("GameMaster").GetComponent<GameMaster>().GameOver();
```

like this